# lua http.request return attempt to index global 'http' (a nil value)

Tags: sockets, lua

I just try simple lua code:

```
local http = require("socket.http")
local  b, c, h = http.request("http://www.example.com/")
```

But I get this error:

```
stdin:1: attempt to index global 'http' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

luasocket is installed and lua find it, anyone can help?

Comment: Are you sure that your above code produces this error? I'm asking because you're actually attempting to index a *local*, not a *global*. However, have you tried using `socket.http` instead?

Comment: Yes, in Lua shell I type two above commands, but when I use **socket.http** instead **http**, it work without error, but b,c,h variables are **nil**

Comment: Oh, I just write this two lines in a file instead of lua shell, and now it works! Thanks and sorry for silly question, it's first time I'm using Lua.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lua repl runs each line in its own context. Local variables don't stick around from line to line. Drop the local on the first line and `http` will be available in the second line in the repl.

If `b`, `c` and `h` are nil that sounds like the call failed for some reason.

Comment: Yes! I'm new in lua, Thanks.